# TreeView in Angular 8 from complex json

Tags: json, angular, treeview

1. I want to create a TreeView in Angular with complex json data without restructuring it into a specific format.I have used `jqTree` but it needs restructure of JSON into a particular format as it cannot pick up the hierarchy automatically.
2. Also, my requirement states I need multiple treeViews in one screen with the capability to assign nodes with each other.For example there is `Tree1` created with `In` object of json and Tree2 created with `Out` object of json(JSON object is mentioned below).I want to assign a node from `Out` to In. If it can be done using drag and drop then its the best or a button
   click to move nodes should also be fine.I tried to do that manually
   through button click but i had to find out the parent nodes and
   browse through the formatted structure to move it between
   treeviews which is more error prone in case the hierarchy of json
   changes.

Is it possible in any other way? Below is the json mentioned in the question.

```
{
"In": {
    "Parts": {
        "Main": {
            "ABC": {
                "Byte0": {
                    "Bit0.0": {},
                    "Bit0.1": {},
                    "Bit0.2": {},
                    "Bit0.3": {},
                    "Bit0.4": {},
                    "Bit0.5": {},
                    "Bit0.6": {},
                    "Bit0.7": {}
                },
                "Byte1": {
                    "Bit1.0": {},
                    "Bit1.1": {},
                    "Bit1.2": {},
                    "Bit1.3": {},
                    "Bit1.4": {},
                    "Bit1.5": {},
                    "Bit1.6": {},
                    "Bit1.7": {}
                }
            },
            "XYZ": {
                "Byte0": {
                    "Bit0.0": {},
                    "Bit0.1": {},
                    "Bit0.2": {},
                    "Bit0.3": {},
                    "Bit0.4": {},
                    "Bit0.5": {},
                    "Bit0.6": {},
                    "Bit0.7": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
},  
    "Out":{
      "Parts": {
        "Main": {
            "ABC": {
                "Byte0": {
                    "Bit0.0": {},
                    "Bit0.1": {},
                    "Bit0.2": {},
                    "Bit0.3": {},
                    "Bit0.4": {},
                    "Bit0.5": {},
                    "Bit0.6": {},
                    "Bit0.7": {}
                },
                "Byte1": {
                    "Bit1.0": {},
                    "Bit1.1": {},
                    "Bit1.2": {},
                    "Bit1.3": {},
                    "Bit1.4": {},
                    "Bit1.5": {},
                    "Bit1.6": {},
                    "Bit1.7": {}
                }
            },
            "XYZ": {
                "Byte0": {
                    "Bit0.0": {},
                    "Bit0.1": {},
                    "Bit0.2": {},
                    "Bit0.3": {},
                    "Bit0.4": {},
                    "Bit0.5": {},
                    "Bit0.6": {},
                    "Bit0.7": {}
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: please follow this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview)

Comment: ngXTreeView needs a particular structure i guess because in the example it says it needs a text value.